# adding fields to scaffolding RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've done scaffolding using the method described here http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ScaffoldGenerator

However, I want to know what do i do if i want to add more fields AFTER I have ran the ./script/generate scaffolding model> propertyname:string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ruby script/generate migration AddFieldToModel field:string
# edit migration if desired
rake db:migrate
```

You'll have to manually update your views.

Edit: More information on migrations can be found in the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html)